# Netsuite - After Field Edit Action in Workflow not being triggered by CSV/Suitelet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have an After Field Edit action in my Workflow which triggers whenever the desired set of fields are changed in UI. However this action is not being triggered when those fields are updated by CSV Import or a Suitelet Script.

I've not selected anything in 'Contexts' section in my action so that it allows the action to trigger for all contexts.

Can someone please let me know what events in a Workflow are triggered when updating field via CSV Import or 'nlapiSubmitField' in a Script?

Best Regards,
Anish

Answer (score 6):

You need to check the box "Run server Suitescript and trigger Workflows" during the Import Assistant:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw5S5.jpg[image: This]

Answer (score 0):

`After Field Edit` is a client-sided trigger and therefore cannot be triggered by a CSV import. Only server-sided triggers like `After Record Submit` can be triggered by a CSV import